# Concept clarification on baseband system model of LO leakage impairments in 5G NR?

Tags: digital-communications, ofdm, lte

I am trying to generate a baseband (BB) system model with LO leakage impairments and correction.

The channel bandwidth $BW = 20$ MHz, Subcarrier Spacing $= 15$ kHz, oversampling rate = $4$ (just oversampling the generated signal in time domain). Time duration = $10$ ms. Sampling Rate $F_s$= 122.88 MHz

**Generate Signal in time domain:**

```
txbb=[1228800 X 1]; % generate dimension [1228800 by 1] BB signal in time domain
```

**RF Impairment addition (LO leakage):**

```
Nfft=length(txbb)
RFImpLOFreq=[1; zeros(Nfft-1,1)] % Freq domain LO leakage at zero Frequency [1228800*1]
RFImpLOTime=ifft(RFImpLoFreq,Nfft) * Nfft;* %Time domain LO leakage
```

**Generated Signal + Impairments:**

```
TxImpaired=txbb+RFImpLOTime;  % BB signal with LO impairment
```

**LO Leakage Correction:**

```
TxCorrected=TxImpaired-mean(TxImpaired);
```

***Questions:***

1. Is my LO leakage modeling at BB correct? The reason I ask is because I just added a **single sample (0 Hz) in frequency domain** with a fixed magnitude (the rest of them are zero in frequency domain). Am I missing something?
2. **The mean of `txbb` is not zero, or always zero**. Therefore I am suspecting that when I do LO leakage correction some of the original signal information might be lost?

Comment: Re 1.: why do that? As explained by AlexTP and I in your previous questions, real-world hardware doesn't do that, and the DC carrier simply remains unused. No problem to be solved, so don't solve the problem which is none.

Comment: Re 2.: yeah, that's because there's nothing sent on DC, so there's nothing to be removed.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I understand what you are saying. But I just wanted to built a baseband model for this LO impairemetns with carrier center at DC.

Comment: but that simply is not a model of a 5G NR device.